# Using reset css - any reasonable drawbacks/counterarguments?

Tags: css, reset

So far, including a CSS reset was a standard step for me at the very beginning of web page designing.

I heard once the opinion that this is *bad*; however I had no opportunity to ask the guy who said that for the reasons.

Now I'd like to know what drawbacks can you specify.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are CSS Frameworks Really Worth Using?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/506523/are-css-frameworks-really-worth-using)

Comment: Good question but already discussed several times. See also http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=css+frameworks

Comment: I don't really want to talk about CSS frameworks. the difference between the reset and the complete css framework is the overhead which comes with the layout / grid styles.

Comment: I'm sorry, I must have been sleeping. Resets, however, have also been discussed before, even more extensively than frameworks. This is probably the best one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/167531/is-it-ok-to-use-a-css-reset-stylesheet more here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=css+reset

Comment: I don’t see any specifically asking for drawbacks though. I’d keep this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a CSS reset means you, in many cases, will have many rules that are not necessary. You will first set `body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }` in reset.css and then set `body { margin: 0 auto; padding: 20px; }` in style.css or something, when only specifying the latter would give the same result. And will you really use all those obscure elements that are included in the reset?

What I sometimes do is that I add a reset.css, start coding, and then I check my page in Dragonfly or Firebug and there I will see which rules from reset.css are overridden. Those I can remove from reset.css, and in the end the file is likely to be very small or empty.

Comment: Your method sounds good. One question though — how big is the “unnecessary rules” issue? Have you saved a lot of bandwidth removing the overridden rules? I would have thought with any reasonably substantial stylesheet, it’d be a pretty small percentage.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is any problems with css resets as a concept.
The only problem maybe using the wrong reset like the * reset which may have performance penalty for the browser.
If using something like Eric Meyer's css reset  http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/index.html then you wont have any problems.
The other advice is you can tweak the reset to your specific needs and not treat it as a read only file :).