# Django theme/skin repository

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Is there some place of freely available themes/skins for standard Django apps? I mean the typical stuff containing footer, header, etc.

Comment: any html template should be useable within the template system no? do you have a particular app in mind?

Comment: What do you mean by "standard Django Apps"?  Which apps?

Comment: I'm looking for this typical 3 column style theme + footer + header, you find in most sites tody. Just so that I can replace some graphics and CSS and find most of the typical djange template variables already in place (title, etc)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If your question refers to django-admin app, you could try [Grappeli](http://code.google.com/p/django-grappelli/).
If not, you may like to get familiar with CSS Frameworks. Useful resources can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203069/what-is-the-best-css-framework-and-are-they-worth-the-effort) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647853/how-do-you-choose-a-css-framework). I would personally recommend [960.gs](http://960.gs/), but it's a matter of taste.

Answer (score 9):

Take a look at [djangoslingshot.com](http://www.djangoslingshot.com) (full disclosure, it's my site).

One of the products is "template templates" -- there are two templates currently available under CC Attribute license.

Comment: Deleting my comment just a heads up then =) Site looks interesting gonna have to take a closer look.

Comment: Are you still working on it? Looks like a pretty cool project.