# IE friendly CSS framework

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-frameworks, cascade-framework

I need a CSS framework that is friendly with Internet Explorer. It also needs to be compatible (by compatible, I mean work nicely) with jQuery.

I need to be able to easily create a website based on [this](http://imm.io/56jL) layout design. I know that this is a very n00bish question, but I am just rubbish at setting up a simply layout for a website, I prefer server side programming.

I have tried Blueprint CSS and created it successfully, but it is messing up with my jQuery or [Spark JS](http://sparkjs.co.uk/). So Blueprint is a no go for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is a css framework comparison :

http://synapse.neural9.com/css-frameworks-comparison-chart/

this also may help you :

[How do you choose a CSS framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647853/how-do-you-choose-a-css-framework)

Answer (score 5):

Try [Cascade Framework](http://jslegers.github.io/cascadeframework/).

- **Flexibility:** You won't find any framework that has a more flexible grid system or better browser support. Its panel, tab block, table and navigation components also provide unprecedented flexibility.
- **Lightweight:** If you use only Cascade Framework's core features, you'll need to include only 8.5 kb (2.6 kb gzipped) of framework CSS code. If you want everything, including all Fontawesome icons, you'll need to include 51.9 kb (10.8 kb gzipped) of framework CSS code. If that's still too much, there's also a fatfree minimal version called [**Cascade Framework Light**](http://jslegers.github.io/cascadeframeworklight/).
- **Cross-Browser Compatible:** Cascade Framework allows you to create a responsive layout in all modern browsers. In IE6-8, you'll serve the desktop version of your website.
- **Modular:** Cascade Framework provides you with several individual modules as well as a couple of builds (combining individual modules). Cascade Framework 2 will be re-written in SCSS and offer far more customization features.