# Benefits of using a CSS framework

Tags: css, frameworks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best CSS Framework and are they worth the effort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203069/what-is-the-best-css-framework-and-are-they-worth-the-effort)

Would you recommend using a CSS framework for ASP.NET like the Blueprint CSS Framework vs building your own css styles? What are the benefits of using such a framework?

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203069/what-is-the-best-css-framework-and-are-they-worth-the-effort

Comment: Sorry, I did not find it when I searched the first time.

Answer (score 5):

Abstraction is the keyword.

Like every framework it delivers you a code basis you can build on. You don't have to "reinvent the wheel".

Answer (score 4):

Ever considered using CSS resets?  They're much simpler and allow you to start from the ground up.

I have heard of CSS frameworks but don't really understand the level of complexity they introduce.

That said, I do tend to write standard CSS and expect browsers to conform to it.  If not perfectly, then similarly across them all.

Answer (score 2):

I think the benefits are:

1.Easier to follow web standards.

2.You code will be consistent across the projects, and for that reason much easier for maintenance.

And definatelly give a look to reset and fonts-reset

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why using CSS Frameworks.

I always do my CSS from scratch, sometimes to remember sometimes i go back to my older CSS styles and look around. And sometimes i just do some testing until I've obtained what i wanted.

EDIT: Just read some of the web standards guidelines and do some experiment and you will get the hand of it..

I did the same and at my first times.. I had some cross-browser issues and other small stuff.
now i'm pretty happy to say that i do cross-browser css, with no big problem.

But if you just need CSS for a project, and you wont be needing CSS again, using a Framework might not be a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion a CSS framework:

**PROS**

1. Aims at cutting down development
   time.
2. Standardization and consistency.
3. Solid foundation to build upon.
4. Guidance\guidelines to follow. Avoid white screen of death effect.
5. Proven "good looking" UI.

**CONS**

1. Extra complexity
2. Steep learning curve

...

Answer (score 1):

PROS: Anyone can take it and produce a result

CONS: Not everybody will be able to fix what comes out of it...

Answer (score 0):

I would defenitely use a CSS framework, simply because you can assume it has been tested in a lot of browsers. I you use something like [960.gs](http://960.gs/) and it looks correct in one browser, you can be quite sure it will do so in all the others.

And like Omega notes I would at least use a CSS reset file, like [YUI Reset CSS](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/).

Answer (score 0):

I like to use CSS frameworks because it ensures that it looks (quite) the same in many different browsers. e.g. I'm sick of writing hacks for internet explorer 6. The framework take this part for me.

The con is that you have to learn how to use the framework of your choise, but once learned it makes fun to write new sites.

I'm using [YAML](http://www.yaml.de/en/home.html) btw.