# Which is the most versatile CSS framework for different types of layouts?

Tags: html, css

I would like to know which is the most versatile CSS layout applicable to most or all types of different layouts?

Comment: Can you please rephrase the question? Not exactly sure what you mean.

Comment: different layouts such as two column, three column, fluid, fixed, etc

Comment: What is a "CSS framework" anyway?

Comment: @che: nothing good. rant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203069

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No CSS Framework can possibly be applicable to all different types of layouts, you will have to choose depending on what type of website you're building.

However, most layouts can be divided into grids... therefore it can be a good idea to pick a grid-based framework, like the [960 grid](http://960.gs/) or [Blueprint CSS](http://www.blueprintcss.org/) for example.

Comment: ok i see, but i was wondering for something better than others.

Comment: then I would say the 960-grid or Blueprint, see edits in my post for links.

Answer (score 0):

Try [YUI Grids](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/grids/). I found it very powerful and well documented.

Comment: YUI grids also has a builder that you can experiment with layouts and then generate the CSS and HTML stubs for it.

Answer (score 0):

[Tripoli Framework](http://devkick.com/lab/tripoli/) supports **IE5**.

If you need IE5 or any old frameworks, go with it. Some other frameworks are really bloated.

Comment: Just Say NO! to IE < 7. Please, the world will be a better place for it.

Comment: IE 6 still is a fast browser and someone who has nothing other than a 486 pc can still read pages relying on a good framework. And keeping the structure/grid in place for even something like IE6 or 5 is nothing bad. It's the opposite: friendly. And yes: get blueprint Css.

Answer (score 0):

[Zurb Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com) is really nice. Lots of pre-made styles and templates. The javascript plugins are optional, and everything is responsive (fits to any screen). There's a good amount of documentation and a fair size community to answer any questions you might have.