# What do I use if a CSS framework or grid is bad?

Tags: css, grid

Reference this question:

[What is the best CSS Framework and are they worth the effort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203069/what-is-the-best-css-framework-and-are-they-worth-the-effort)

Do I go back to the "old" way of manually creating a template or downloading free ones again.  For a little bit I thought a grid was the new thing and the best, now it appears I am wrong after all and not sure of best practice.

And, yes, I can write my own CSS but didn't want to create the infrastructure if I didn't have to.

Answer (score 0):

Perosnally I use the YUI stylesheets and sometimes the YUI grid builder. I don't use their whole framework, but just some of their stylesheets. It keeps everything really lightweight and it's still all just standard CSS.

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/grids/

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with using a framework to rapid prototype your design, as long as when that design is approved by your client / boss you clean it up and remove the unnecessary parts.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own grid layout with the [Variable Grid System](http://spry-soft.com/grids/) (css grid framework). It works for fixed and fluid layouts.