# If I prefer semantic naming then shouldn't i use any CSS Framework and grid approach?

Tags: css, xhtml, w3c, semantic-markup

If I prefer **semantic naming** then shouldn't i use any CSS Framework and grid approach?

Which approach is better Grid or Freehand?

Is any CSS Frameworks really can save time and make semantic code even for Experienced CSS developer?

Many CSS Frameworksd are popular in static PSD 2 XHTML+CSS conversion and in wordpress/drupal/joomla theme development.

Can we make CSS XHTML development as faster as with CSS frameworks but without using CSS Grid Frameworks?

What makes development with CSS frameworks faster which we can't do without frameworks?

Comment: You might find these interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203069/what-is-the-best-css-framework-and-are-they-worth-the-effort and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670156/what-css-framework-would-you-recomend

Comment: Side note - due to the fact that CSS is only a styling framework and completely missed the layout problem, you will have hard time sticking to semantically meaningful names even with your own CSS, once you have to stick several extra divs here and there just to get your visual elements where you want them on the screen...

Answer (score 1):

Semantically named classes are a particular pet-peeve of mine, so the approach I adopted was using [960 Grid System](http://960.gs) and [Sass](http://sass-lang.com). The grid system reduces the time I spend creating the layout while Sass allows me to simulate inheritance by using mixins. Something like:

```
=grid_19
  width: 750px;

#main-content
  +grid_19
```

In this example, `#main-content` inherits the properties of `.grid_19`, it's a div with 750px of width (19 columns) with a semantic id. Sure I had to adapt the grid system's CSS to use it with Sass, but once it was made I can reuse its declarations without having to use its non-semantic class names.

I didn't tried any other CSS framework or grid system. I prefer grid systems over doing it by freehand because it's easier and faster. What makes development with CSS frameworks faster? Well, it's already done. I don't need to reinvent the weel. **:)**

Comment: what is Sass can we use it with any type of project in any language. php, asp etc

Comment: Sass is a meta-language built upon CSS (and improved, sure) in which you can declare your styles using nesting, variables and mixins and later "compiling" it to CSS using its ruby app. You can see more on its site (the link is in my answer) and yes, you can use it with any language. Your code won't see Sass, it's independent of the rest of your code.

Comment: So will i need ruby installed on my webserver. and I don't programming in ruby. still can i use Sass?