# Is there any common CSS library?

Tags: css, css-frameworks

I'm looking for CSS library that hold all common css best practices.

For example block centering style:

```
.block-center {
   margin-left : auto;
   margin-right : auto;
}

<div class="myClass block-center" />
```

I want such library to be distributed as separate css file which I can add and use in my projects.

Comment: Because of a) CSS needs to be transmitted through the interweb tubes and b) Every website is unique, for most parts it is usually best to hand craft CSS for every website. The only exception is grid and reset scripts, but those hardly counts as 'libraries' as you'd put it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you mean *CSS framework*: there are **tons** of them. Just to name a few:

- [Blueprint](http://blueprintcss.org/)
- [BlueTrip](http://bluetrip.org/)
- [Boilerplate](http://code.google.com/p/css-boilerplate/)
- [Content with Style](http://www.contentwithstyle.co.uk/content/a-css-framework)
- [Elastic](http://elasticss.com/)
- [Elements](http://elements.projectdesigns.org/)
- [Mollio](http://www.mollio.org/)
- [960 Grid System](http://960.gs/)
- [1KB Grid](http://www.1kbgrid.com/)
- [SenCSs](http://sencss.kilianvalkhof.com/)
- [Tripoli](http://devkick.com/lab/tripoli/)
- [Typogridphy](http://csswizardry.com/typogridphy/)
- [YAML](http://www.yaml.de/en/)
- [YUI Grids](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/grids/)

Everyone and their mother has a CSS Framework: there is no *best* one, and they all have their own interpretation of what constitutes "best practices". it really depends on what one fits your own use.

Also see [bobince](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18936/bobince)'s answer on [What is the best CSS Framework and are they worth the effort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203069/what-is-the-best-css-framework-and-are-they-worth-the-effort/203133#203133) for why CSS Frameworks are really unnecessary.

Comment: Note:  Anyone who asks which CSS framework to use, is really asking, "By now, there must be a subset of things that will work everywhere.  I'm happy with that.  Which one delivers that?"  They (we) will not have spent the obsessive time gaining the experience to make CSS unnecessary.  It's better to learn it all yourself of course, but a bunch of boxes will do.

Comment: The problem is that CSS frameworks are trivial to make, which gives everyone and anyone the ability to say "no, my way is the right way." Getting everyone to agree on the same best practices when it comes to starting CSS is like herding cats.

Comment: it appears your fav has been retired, as the link now re-directs. Maybe consider updating your answer.

Comment: @ted.strauss Removed: Unobstrusive CSS was just a splash page that provided a tongue-in-cheek framework (something like `* {}`) to make the  point that writing semantic HTML  lets you avoid having to use a rigid framework in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

You should try using [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html),  it is very easy to use, there are many YouTube tutorials.

I stopped using other CSS methods after finding out about it.