# Usage of Web Template in JSP Form

Tags: html, css, templates, jsp

I have designed few JSP forms and I am in need of integrating any web template in that JSP form.

I am a beginner in JSP and I am completely unaware of such web templates usage in JSP.

**Any sort of explanation/sources that would help me in proceeding with my task would be of great help.**

Thanks everyone in advance. Waiting for your helpful replies.

**UPDATE**

Also let me know model web templates that can be downloaded from net. My ultimate aim is to present my JSP form in a good way.

Comment: Your question is vague and ambiguous. The term "web template" makes no sense. Are you actually talking about [CSS](http://www.csstutorial.net/)? If so, this is completely unrelated to JSP. CSS acts on HTML which is served by JSP.

Comment: am completely unaware of the CSS :( But I want my JSP forms to be presented in a good way. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is completely unrelated to JSP. JSP just offers a way to control the HTML/CSS/JS output programmatically using Java. All the browser gets and understands is HTML/CSS/JS. You control markup with HTML. You control style (look'n'feel) with CSS. You control progressive enhancements with JS.

So, the real answer is: use [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets).

#### References:

- [CSS tutorial](http://www.csstutorial.net/)
- [CSS reference](http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp)
- [CSS best practices](http://www.alistapart.com/)
- [CSS web design for Dummies](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0764584251)

#### Related questions:

- [What's the best CSS framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203069/what-is-the-best-css-framework-and-are-they-worth-the-effort)

Comment: Thanks Balus. And hearty congrats on earning 100000 reputation :)